# Developer story network sites include meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, user-interface

On the developer story page I can choose which communities to display. Currently this includes all the meta sites, which are actually listed *before* the main site.

[image]

Aside from Meta Stack Exchange, I don't see the value of listing these at all. And if there is a value, it's not very good UI design right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been fixed and will be up with the next build. We kept Meta Stack Exchange, but removed all child meta sites from the list of communities users can choose to display on their developer stories.